# how to make a inline hexagon gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
  .hexagon-gallery {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: 200px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
  }
  
  .hex {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 240px;
    height: 265px;
    background-color: #424242;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
  }
  
  .hex:first-child {
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-column: 3 / span 2;
  }
  
  .hex:nth-child(2) {
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-column: 4 / span 2;
  }
  
  .hex:nth-child(3) {
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-column: 6 / span 2;
  }
```

```html
       <section class="hexagon-gallery">
            <div class="hex"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1421264/pexels-photo-1421264.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=aerial-aerial-photo-aerial-photography-1421264.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="some"></div>
            <div class="hex"></div>
            <div class="hex"></div>
          </section>
```

[image]

Im trying to aim for something of a similar shape. Hexagon stretched typo shape , idk if there any other easier way to do this.Maybe a rectangle with both sides shaped could work I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would that work ? I tidied the code a bit to remove extraneous CSS properties.

The main parts are:

- `clip-path: polygon(85% 0%, 100% 50%, 85% 100%, 15% 100%, 0% 50%, 15% 0%);` to get the right shape.
- `grid-auto-flow: column;` and `grid-auto-columns: 168px;` (which is your `.hex` width -30%, since the shape cuts 15% on each side) to align the items correctly.`
- The `z-index` which should be in a decrement sequence so each item always cover the next one. If you remove the `z-index` you'll have the opposite effect (each element covered by the next one), as by default in HTML, an element at the bottom of its group of siblings appears "above" the elements above it.
- And just for tidyness `grid-auto-rows: 0px;` which replace the `grid-row-start: 1;` on each element.

```css
.hexagon-gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 0px;
  grid-auto-columns: 168px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.hex {
  display: flex;
  width: 240px;
  height: 265px;
  clip-path: polygon(85% 0%, 100% 50%, 85% 100%, 15% 100%, 0% 50%, 15% 0%);
}

.hex:first-child {
  background: red;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.hex:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
  z-index: 900;
}

.hex:nth-child(3) {
  background: blue;
  z-index: 800;
}
```

```html
<section class="hexagon-gallery">
  <div class="hex"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1421264/pexels-photo-1421264.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=aerial-aerial-photo-aerial-photography-1421264.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="some"></div>
  <div class="hex"></div>
  <div class="hex"></div>
</section>
```

To tweak the shape, modify the `85%` and `15%` (they should always add up to 100 if you want to keep a symmetric shape).
For example putting 75% and 25% instead will make the angle bigger.
Don't forget to change the `grid-auto-columns` value to `width * (25*2)%`, so `120px` in this case to keep the correct spacing between each element.
Example with these parameters:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hello I am not a hundred percent sure that that is what you are looking for, but please take a look.

I used two css custom properties to make it work(
`--max` which refers to max elements per row
`--order` which refers to the order of the element
)

```css
.hexagon-gallery {
    --max: 4;

    margin-inline: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    max-width: fit-content;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--max, 1), 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: 200px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
  }
  
  .hex {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #424242;
    width: 200px;
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
    z-index: calc(var(--max, 1) - var(--order, 0));
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .hex > img {
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  
  .hex:not(:first-child) {
    transform: translateX(calc(calc(var(--order, 1) - 1) * -40%));
  }
```

```html
<section class="hexagon-gallery">
  <div class="hex" style="--order: 1;"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1421264/pexels-photo-1421264.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=aerial-aerial-photo-aerial-photography-1421264.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="some"></div>
  <div class="hex" style="--order: 2;"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1421264/pexels-photo-1421264.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=aerial-aerial-photo-aerial-photography-1421264.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="some"></div>
  <div class="hex" style="--order: 3;"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1421264/pexels-photo-1421264.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=aerial-aerial-photo-aerial-photography-1421264.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="some"></div>
  <div class="hex" style="--order: 4;"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1421264/pexels-photo-1421264.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=aerial-aerial-photo-aerial-photography-1421264.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="some"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: If you want the same shape as the reference image, you can use `clip-path: polygon(80% 20%, 100% 60%, 80% 100%, 20% 100%, 0% 60%, 20% 20%);`

Comment: @AStombaugh That's cool, but I tried to keep most parts of his own code, jsut so he could see the differences.

Comment: That was directed at him. I posted essentially the same answer but then I saw yours and deleted mine since we don't need two of the same answer on the question. I just wanted to include the code for the shape in the reference.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to compute the `z-index` for the active slide and each subsequent slide from the left and the right. The active hexagon will have the highest `z-index`. The hexagons furthest away (left and right), will have a much lower `z-index`; much like a bell curve.

**Tip:** There is a play/pause button below the carousel (scroll-down).

```js
const
  gallery = document.querySelector('.hexagon-gallery'),
  slides = gallery.querySelectorAll('.hex'),
  refreshRate = 2000;
let activeIndex = 0, intervalId;

const update = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    const
      slide = slides[i],
      newIndex = ((slides.length - i) + activeIndex) % slides.length,
      zIndex = ((activeIndex - Math.abs(activeIndex - i)) + slides.length) * 100;
    slide.style.zIndex = zIndex;
    slide.classList.remove('active');
  }
  activeIndex = (activeIndex + 1) % slides.length;
  slides[activeIndex].classList.add('active');
};

const play = () => {
  intervalId = setInterval(update, refreshRate);
};

const pause = () => {
  if (intervalId) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    intervalId = null;
  }
};

const toggleAction = (e) => {
  if (intervalId) {
    pause() ; e.target.textContent = 'Play';
  } else {
    play()  ; e.target.textContent = 'Pause';
  }
}

document.querySelector('[data-action="pause"]').addEventListener('click', toggleAction);

play();
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
  background: #222;
}

.hexagon-gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 120px;
  max-width: 360px;
}

.hex {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #424242;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(15% 0%, 85% 0%, 100% 50%, 85% 100%, 15% 100%, 0% 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(15% 0%, 85% 0%, 100% 50%, 85% 100%, 15% 100%, 0% 50%);
}

.hex:nth-child(1) {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}
.hex:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
}
.hex:nth-child(3) {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-column: 3 / span 2;
}
.hex:nth-child(4) {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-column: 4 / span 2;
}
.hex:nth-child(5) {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-column: 5 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<section class="hexagon-gallery">
  <div class="hex">
    <img
      src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1421264/pexels-photo-1421264.jpeg"
      alt="Beach">
  </div>
  <div class="hex">
    <img
      src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/54323/rose-composites-flowers-spring-54323.jpeg"
      alt="Rose">
  </div>
  <div class="hex">
    <img
      src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/102104/pexels-photo-102104.jpeg"
      alt="Apple">
  </div>
  <div class="hex">
    <img
      src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1343537/pexels-photo-1343537.jpeg"
      alt="Lemon">
  </div>
  <div class="hex">
    <img
      src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3686216/pexels-photo-3686216.jpeg"
      alt="Flower">
  </div>
</section>
<button data-action="pause">Pause</button>
```